# Are there two meanings to this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I didn't know she was going to be there until 5 minutes before service.

Is it ambiguous?

> 1 I didn't know until 5 minutes before service that she was going to
> be there.
>
> or
>
> 2 I didn't know that she was going to remain there (only) until 5 minutes before
> service.

Comment: Yes, it could mean two things.

Comment: Both seem to me to mean the same.

Comment: @KateBunting in case 1, the narrator realises 5 minutes before the service, in case 2, "she" is there until 5 minutes before the service (and presumably left then)

Comment: @mattfreake - Oh, I see - thanks. Of course, in speech the difference would be obvious from the intonation.

Comment: https://www.shmoop.com/quotes/i-shot-an-elephant-in-my-pajamas.html

Answer (score 2):

There is more ambiguity in the second version than the first, though from context it ought to be easy to know which meaning was intended.

> I didn't know that she was going to be there until 5 minutes before service, and then have to leave.
>
> I didn't know that she was going to be there until 5 minutes before service, when she surprised me by walking into the kitchen.

The first seems clearer, that you had no idea she would turn up until she did, just before some timed event.

btw, 'before service' implies a restaurant/kitchen. If you meant a church, then you would use 'before *the* service'.

Comment: +1 for showing how context can clear up the ambiguity! I'd give you another +1 if I could for explaining "service" vs. "the service".

Comment: But if you substitute _mass_ for _service_, you don't need the article! (Also for named services such as _Evensong_ or _Matins_; but they are names. _Mass_ isn't). Isn't English wonderful.